# Managing Jira issues at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-jira-trigger

I am using Jenkins JIRA plugin.
When the job is done, I am creating new Jira version and then moving Resolved, Closed, Done jiras to this new version.
[image]

But the problem is only Resolved and Done jiras are moved. The Closed one stays at old version. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this because of closed jira tickets cannot be updated/moved.you can make them editable through the workflow. for more information you can follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/allow-editing-of-closed-issues-138704.html)